# Showing Text for a sertain amount of seconds in lua

Tags: lua

My question is: is there a way in lua to display text for a sertain amount of seconds?? I am trying to make a little gui and I want to display my logo (I used the print statement with --'s to make it) for 3 seconds. Plz help me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: (1) show the logo, (2) wait for three seconds, (3) hide the logo. If you know how to do steps 1 and 3, then for step 2 you have a couple of options.

If you have access to a library like luasocket, you may use its [select](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#select) call that will wait for a number of seconds:

```
socket.select(nil, nil, 3)
```

If this library is not available, you can do a "busy" loop:

```
local start = os.time()
while os.time() < start + 3 do end
```

This is definitely not the best option and this keeps the CPU busy and doesn't guarantee that the wait time will be 3 seconds depending on where you catch the current timer, but it may not matter in your case.

This is partially [tongue-in-cheek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek), but if you need answers on how to do steps 1 and 3, then you need to be much more specific in your question as there is no general way to do this and the answer very much depends on libraries you are using or have access to.